# Flutter BottomNavigationBar never changes highlighted option despite setting 'currentIndex'

Tags: flutter, menu, bottomnavigationview

I must be having a blond moment here; what I want to do is so simple, but I cannot figure it out.

I have a `BottomNavigationBar`, and it works just fine for navigating to different pages, but the bottom bar always shows the first item as the current one, it is always the highlighted one.

I am using `setState` to change the `currentIndex`, and I can see that is happening, but the bottom bar never changes.

Here is the code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myfestival/models/app_config_model.dart';
import 'package:myfestival/pages/user_mode/menus/user_app_named_routes.dart';

class BottomMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomMenu({super.key, required this.menus});

  final List<AppMenu> menus;

  @override
  State<BottomMenu> createState() => _BottomMenuState();
}

class _BottomMenuState extends State<BottomMenu> {

  int? currentIndex;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    print('current index is $currentIndex');

    return BottomNavigationBar(
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      currentIndex: currentIndex??0,
      items: [
        for (final menu in widget.menus.take(5))
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: menu.smallIcon,
            label: menu.title,
          ),
      ],
      onTap: (value) {
        setState(() {currentIndex = value;});
        UserAppRouter.navigateToMenu(context, widget.menus[value]);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the output from clicking the different bottom buttons (I have 3):

```
current index is null
current index is 2
current index is null
current index is 1
current index is null
current index is 2
current index is null
current index is 0
current index is null
current index is 1
current index is null
current index is 2
```

But the bottom bar never looks different to this:

[image]

(ie. the first item is always the selected one)

#### What am I missing?

#### Why won't the highlighted bottom bar option ever change?

Comment: I have identified that the issue is due/related to the fact that I am reusing the same scaffold every time I do the `navigateToMenu` call - if I comment out that line then the bottom highlighting does change - though of course it doesn't actually change page then - ironic I guess.  The way the thing is structured, I think I do need the full new scaffold each time --- how can I make it know what page it is on to set the index?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `null` print is a giveaway that probably every time you call navigation, you don't pass the argument of the current index selected, and because of that, it is always undefined when the widget is drawn.

One solution could be to make the **currentIndex** mandatory and use it as an argument, every time you call the widget.

An alternative is to create a global variable to store the `currentIndex` and make sure the widget reads on the build call.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @andre's answer,  I'm sure this is considered quite hacky, but it seemed simple enough;

I created this to keep track of the index:

```
class BottomMenuIndexProvider {
  static int index = 0;
}
```

Then in my `BottomNavigationBar`,
I set `currentIndex: BottomMenuIndexProvider.index,`
and `onTap` I do `BottomMenuIndexProvider.index = value;` before doing the page routing.